# Why does this goroutine not receive the sent value on the channel

Tags: go

I send http requests on the channel and return a channel to read off each request:

```
func reqs(done <-chan bool, reqs ...*http.Request) chan *http.Request {
        out := make(chan *http.Request)

        go func() {

                defer close(out)
                for _, r := range reqs {
                        select {
                        case out <- r:
                        case <-done:
                                return
                        }

                }
        }()

        return out
}
```

2. I have a type with a method to read the request off the channel.

```
func (a *ReadReq) req1(done chan bool, ch chan *http.Request) chan []byte {
        out := make(chan []byte)

        go func(ch chan *http.Request) {

                defer close(out)
                r, ok := <-ch
                
                if !ok{
                panic("no value received on channel for req1")
                } 

                rb, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)

                if err != nil {
                        panic(err)
                }

                errj := json.Unmarshal(rb, a)

                if errj != nil {
                        panic(errj)
                }

                rbody := a.withdrawRequest().inAmount()
                bb, errbb := json.Marshal(rbody)

                if errbb != nil {
                        panic(errbb)
                }

                select {
                case out <- bb:
                case <-done:
                        return
                }
        }(ch)

        return out
}
```

3. When I call the function `a.req1(done, ch)`, the request is not received on the channel

```
func (a *ReadReq) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        done := make(chan bool)
        defer close(done)

        ch := reqs(done, r)

        for request := range ch {
                err := request.ParseForm()
                if err != nil{
                panic(err)
                }

                switch param := request.Form.Get("reqx"); param {
                case "001":
                        chreq1 := a.req1(done, ch)
                        w.Write(<-chreq1)
                        return

                case "002":
                        chreq2 := a.req2(done, ch)
                        w.Write(<-chreq2)
                        return
                }
        }

}
```

Where am I going wrong in this implemenation.

Comment: Are you aware that [each HTTP request is already handled in its own goroutine](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Serve)? This means that you are (attempting to) unmarshaling into a single *ReadReq concurrently, which is a race condition. What is your goal with this code?

Comment: @Peter thank you peter, yes I am aware requests are handled in goroutines, the code is meant to process many requests from the same client using only 1 handler and endpoint. 

each request sends a piece of data to be processed before other requests can accepted. 

if you know a better way, am all ears

Comment: Consider using sync.Mutex for global serialization or [golang.org/x/sync/singleflight](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/singleflight) if you need namespacing.

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your code to 3 functions, and explained reasons in comments:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// pass parameters into channel and handle them orderly
// f1 will work properly
func f1(doneCh chan bool, args ...int) chan int {
    argCh := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        defer close(argCh) // cause
        for _, arg := range args {
            select {
            case argCh <- arg:
            case <-doneCh:
                return
            }
        }
        fmt.Println("f1: exit loop goroutine, close the argCh")
    }()
    return argCh
}

func f2(n int) {
    doneCh := make(chan bool)
    defer close(doneCh)

    argCh := f1(doneCh, n)
    for arg := range argCh {
        // 1. we taken the ONLY ONE arg from argCh, just like you taken request object from out channel
        fmt.Printf("f2: taken %d from argCh\n", arg)

        // 2. now f1 goroutine exiting the loop, and argCh channel will be defer closed

        // here is the problem
        // 3. you passed the CLOSED channel argCh info f3
        outCh := f3(doneCh, argCh)
        fmt.Println("f3 result:", <-outCh)
    }
}

func f3(doneCh chan bool, inCh chan int) chan int {
    outCh := make(chan int)
    go func(ch chan int) {
        defer close(outCh)
        n, ok := <-ch
        fmt.Printf("f3: n: %d, ok: %t\n", n, ok)
        // want 10, true
        // got  0, false
        // since ch has been closed, the false is expected, 0 is default value of channel type which shouldn't be used
        select {
        case outCh <- n + 1:
        case <-doneCh:
            return
        }
    }(inCh)
    return outCh
}

func main() {
    f2(999)
}
```

output:

```sh
f1: exit loop goroutine, close the argCh
f2: taken 999 from argCh
f3: n: 0, ok: false
f3 result: 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but  what do you mean by ```// 2. now f1 goroutine exiting the loop, and argCh channel will be defer closed```. Does it mean after ranging over the channel ```argCh``` it is closed?

Comment: Yes.
1. f1() start a goroutine to iterate args slice, the args ONLY have 1 element which is 999; 
2. in f2(), we taken the ONLY ONE element from it , the f1() for-range iteration will be done, and f1 goroutine will be exited, defer close(argCh) will be executed, finally lead to close the channel